# WCF REST Service - HTTP 404 error while execution

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, iis, basic-authentication

I am using **WCF REST service** with **basic authentication(UserName / Password)** in **IIS**.

My interface - **ICustomer.cs** is as below:

```
namespace SampleService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustomer
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
             RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             UriTemplate = "/Customer/{email}")]
        string GetCustomerID(string email);
    }
}
```

**Customer.svc** is as below:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="SampleService.Customer" CodeBehind="Customer.svc.cs" %>
```

**Customer.svc.cs**:

```
namespace SampleService
{
    public class Customer : ICustomer
    {
        public string GetCustomerID(string strEmail)
        {
            string returnJsonString = bllContactDetails.GetCustomerID(strEmail).ToString(Formatting.None);
            WebOperationContext customContext;
            customContext = Utility.General.SetCustomHttpStatusCode(returnJsonString);
            return returnJsonString;
        }
    }    

    public class RestAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
    {

        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            //Extract the Authorization header, and parse out the credentials converting the Base64 string:
            var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
            if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
            {
                var svcCredentials = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
                        .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)))
                        .Split(':');
                var user = new { Name = svcCredentials[0], Password = svcCredentials[1] };
                if ((user.Name == "testuser" && user.Password == "testpassword"))
                {
                    //User is authrized and originating call will proceed
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //not authorized
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No authorization header was provided, so challenge the client to provide before proceeding:
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"MyWCFService\"");
                //Throw an exception with the associated HTTP status code equivalent to HTTP status 401
                throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have added **Web.Config** as below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" 
                           httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType=" SampleService.RestAuthorizationManager, SampleService"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpServiceBehavior">
          <!-- Important this is the behavior that makes a normal WCF service to REST based service-->
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="SampleService.Customer" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://192.168.0.122:443/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SampleService.ICustomer" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpServiceBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have created **Custom SSL** and also enabled **Basic Authentication** in **IIS**.

When view my IIS hosted WCF service in browser it shows all the list of services. [image: List of services displayed]

But when I try to get data using **Customer.svc** method it is throwing error as below:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

Please find [image: error screenshot with URL for reference.]

***Also, please let me know if it is the correct binding I'm using for obtaining Basic Authentication.***

Comment: Where is your `binding` ? did you set `security mode="Transport"` ? and do you have SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes, I do have set mode="Transport". Also, as I mentioned in the question (before image 1) I have created custom SSL using IIS and added it already.

Comment: The url does not have the application name. Unless you install it as a site in IIS, the url should have the app name like this https://<ip>/appname/Customer.svc/...